# Problem with entry set of java.util.Map

Tags: java, generics, collections, iterator

I'm having a strange problem with the following code works.

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();

for(Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
   // 
}
```

while the code below does not compile.

```
Map map = new HashMap();

for(Entry entry : map.entrySet()) {  // compile error here
   // 
}
```

Any clues?

Comment: Hm. But `Set<Entry> entries = data.entrySet(); for (Entry entry : entries) { .. }` compiles though.

Comment: And you should correct your code. You declare `data` variable but use `map` in cycle. Also may be add imports? As I see you use `import static java.util.Map.Entry;` it's not very obvious though.

Comment: @BalusC it gives `error: incompatible types: for(Map.Entry entry : data.entrySet()) {` java 1.7.0 ubuntu 11.04

Comment: @BalusC nope. For me it doesn't compile on mac, java 1.6.0_26. Same error. Code http://pastebin.com/mnQ6ZweT

Comment: Are you sure its an error and not a "Unchecked type" warning?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Burt has the right reason and Henning expands on it in the comments.  When referencing a member of a raw type, generics don't come into play **at all**, *even generics that don't rely on the type parameter*.

As an example, this should compile just fine...

```
public class DataHolder<T> {
    public List<T> ts;
    public List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
}

//...
DataHolder holder = new DataHolder();
holder.strings.add(Integer.valueOf(42));
```

...even though `T` doesn't need to be mapped to a concrete type to know what the type of `strings` should be.

This is true for generic member *methods* as well, which is what you are running into.  `entrySet` returns the raw type `Set`, not `Set<Entry>`, even though the type parameters would not need to be known to return a `Set<Entry>`.  The behaviour is documented in the [Java Language Specification, section 4.8](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.8):

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), **instance method** (§8.8, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) M of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C. The type of a static member of a raw type C is the same as its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

It's a very "gotcha" rule.

### See also

[Java Class Generics and Method Generics conflicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734248/java-class-generics-and-method-generics-conflicts/5734346#5734346)

Comment: Thought your explanation was confusing and didn't believe your code example was correct (i.e. `strings.add(Integer)` compiles) until I tried it myself.  Immediately, your explanation makes perfect sense, especially the bold and emphasis part.

Answer (score 8):

The `entrySet` method signature is `Set<Map.Entry<K, V>> entrySet()` so you can only refer to `Map.Entry` if you've declared the generic types in the declaration like you did in the first example. In the second you're using raw types, so it's essentially `Set<Object> entrySet()` and you'd need a cast for it to work, e.g.

```
final Map map = new HashMap();

for(final Entry entry : (Set<Entry>)map.entrySet()) {
   // 
}
```

Comment: Why is it `Set<Object> entrySet()` and not `Set<Map.Entry<Object, Object>> entrySet()`?

Comment: @Nikita, that would be meaningful if a raw type was the same as the original type instantiated with unrestricted wildcards. But it can't be, because it is expected that the user of a raw type does not know about generics at all -- therefore it makes sense for its methods always to take and return raw types themselves.

Comment: It's not `Set<Object>`, it's just `Set`.